# hdf5 format explained in simple terms

Tags: python, hdf5

I am trying to understand the gist hdf5 format. But the spec is too verbose.

https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/H5.format.html

Is there a much shorter but self-contained tutorial to explain the key points of hdf5 format without going into too many details?

Also,

- What is the time complexity of adding a dataset as a function of the number of datasets in an hdf5 file?
- What is the time complexity of look up a dataset as a function of the number of datasets in an hdf5 file?

If I just want a key-value (basical a hash but in disk) format but fast lookup/insert/delete, is hdf5 an overkill? Any better format for key-value data? (sqlite3 is an overkill as it supports more than just key-value pairs.)

Comment: Answer to this question would be twice as verbose as the document you linked. For example, time complexities for such operations as you asked would depend on multiple separate factors. it's impossible to put a name on it.

Comment: At least you can give a best case and worst case bound, which should be much simpler.

Comment: There are 2 modules to do this: h5py and pytables. Do you have a preference? If not, pytables has some nice tools to walk all datasets. Look for `File.walk_nodes()` method. As Ulag noted, we would have to repeat the docs you don't want to read. Also, estimating time complexity is somewhat a function of your skills. :-) IMHO, it is pretty easy to work with HDF5. I'm and NOT a developer and manged to teach myself (with a little help from SO).

Comment: Note, there is a Pytables tutorial. It's pretty quick, and shows how to create a dataset, and add data to it. Use this link: [Pytables Tutorial](https://www.pytables.org/usersguide/tutorials.html)